# Rewrite apply function in pandas using simpe Dataframe calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have this piece of code which calculates the values of a column based on values of some existing  columns  on a pandas dataframe.

```
def get_prj_yield(row):
    try:
        prj_yield = row['prj_rev'] / (row['ds'] + row['otb_demand'])
        if pandas.isnull(prj_yield):
            prj_yield = row['otb_rev'] / row['otb_demand']
        return prj_yield 
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
```

this function gets called on the dataframe using the `apply` function.

```
df['prj_yield'] = output_df.apply(get_prj_yield, axis=1)
```

The existing dataframe has more than 1M rows and I want to know if this function can be rewritten using just plain dataframe calculation. Would that add any improvement to the resources consumed ?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of data?

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop, use vectorial code:

```
s1 = df['prj_rev'].div(df['ds'] + df['otb_demand'])
s2 = df['otb_rev'].div(df['otb_demand'])

df['prj_yield'] = s1.mask(s1.eq(0), s2).replace({np.inf: 0, -np.inf: 0})
```

Alternative:

```
import numpy as np

s1 = df['prj_rev'].div(df['ds'] + df['otb_demand'])
s2 = df['otb_rev'].div(df['otb_demand'])
s3 = s1.mask(s1.eq(0), s2)

df['prj_yield'] = s3.where(np.isfinite(s3), 0)
```

Example output:

```
   prj_rev  ds  otb_demand  otb_rev  prj_yield
0        0   2           2        2        1.0
1        2   0           2        2        1.0
2        2   2           0        2        1.0
3        2   2           2        0        0.5
4        0   1           0        1        0.0
5       -2   1          -1        1        0.0
```